# Selenium get text from a table cell (td) with XPath

Tags: python, html, selenium, xpath

The element is `<td>20175</td>`

Xpath of the element is `//*[@id="body"]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[1]`

I want to take **20175** part.

I tried

```
  elems = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("""//*[@id="body"]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[1]""")

  print (elems)
```

But what it gave me this not the text.

```
selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="77dc0a7bef8dadbf9aec1ddbab9e3a91", element="0.027053967816755176-1")>]
```

Comment: try to find another way to get that element from this table long xpath will make you trouble in the future (little change of tables in the website will crush your application)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you see printed is a `WebElement` instance string representation. Instead, get the [`.text`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.text):

```
elem = browser.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="body"]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[1]""")
print(elem.text)
```

Or, if there are multiple elements matching the locator:

```
elems = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("""//*[@id="body"]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[1]""")
print([elm.text for elm in elems])
```

Comment: @MelihMuhammetGundogdu: Best way to thank would be to upvote and [**accept**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5234/234215) this answer if it's helped.